# T-SQL FETCH_STATUS Alternative

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure below.  In it is a nested loop.  Instead of using FETCH_STATUS I want to use something else to mark my cursor as being finished, so that I can do a nested loop.  **But it's never picking up @Client_ID in the cursor and I don't know why.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Import_Agent_Client_Bucket_2010]
AS
BEGIN
    -- Loop Through Each Agent, Create a Bucket, Add their Clients to the Bucket
    DECLARE Agent_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TOP 10 Agent_GUID, Agent_ID
    FROM  realforms_2011.dbo.Agent

    DECLARE @Agent_GUID uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @Agent_ID int

    OPEN Agent_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Agent_Cursor
    INTO @Agent_GUID, @Agent_ID;

    DECLARE @MaxAgentCount int
    SELECT @MaxAgentCount = COUNT(Agent_ID)
    FROM Agent

    DECLARE @AgentCounter int
    SET @AgentCounter = 0

    WHILE (1 < 2)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Agent Counter:'
            PRINT @AgentCounter

            SET @AgentCounter = @AgentCounter + 1
            -- Create a bucket for each agent
            DECLARE @cbPKTable TABLE (cbPK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, cbID int) 

            INSERT INTO realforms_2011.dbo.Client_Bucket ([Description] ) OUTPUT inserted.Client_Bucket_GUID, inserted.Client_Bucket_ID INTO @cbPKTable
            SELECT ISNULL(a.First_Name, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(a.Last_Name, ' ') + '''s Clients'
            FROM  realforms_2011.dbo.Agent a
            WHERE Agent_GUID = @Agent_GUID

            DECLARE @Client_Bucket_GUID uniqueidentifier
            SELECT @Client_Bucket_GUID = cbPK FROM @cbPKTable

            PRINT 'Client Bucket GUID Inserted:'
            PRINT @Client_Bucket_GUID

            DECLARE @Client_Bucket_ID int
            SELECT @Client_Bucket_ID = cbID FROM @cbPKTable

            INSERT INTO realforms_2011.dbo.Agent_Client_Bucket (Agent_GUID, Agent_ID, Client_Bucket_GUID, Client_Bucket_ID)
            VALUES (@Agent_GUID, @Agent_ID, @Client_Bucket_GUID, @Client_Bucket_ID)

            DECLARE @Client_GUID uniqueidentifier
            DECLARE @Client_ID int

            -- Get clients from the server (2010)
            DECLARE Client_Cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT C.Client_ID
            FROM realforms.dbo.Client C
                INNER JOIN realforms.dbo.Agent_Client AC ON AC.Client_ID = C.Client_ID
            WHERE AC.Agent_ID = @Agent_ID 
            ORDER BY C.Client_ID ASC

            DECLARE @MaxClientCreateDate datetime

            SELECT @MaxClientCreateDate = MAX(Create_Date) 
            FROM realforms.dbo.Client C

            PRINT 'Max Create Date:'
            PRINT @MaxClientCreateDate

            DECLARE @ClientCreateDate datetime

            SET @ClientCreateDate = CAST('01-01-2000' AS datetime)

            OPEN Client_Cursor;
            FETCH NEXT FROM Client_Cursor
            INTO @Client_ID
            -- loop through each 2010 client
            WHILE (1 < 2)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @myNewPKTable TABLE (myNewPK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) 

                BEGIN TRY
                    PRINT 'Client ID:'
                    PRINT @Client_ID
                    PRINT 'Agent ID:'
                    PRINT @Agent_ID

                    INSERT INTO realforms_2011.dbo.Client (Client_ID,Name,Secondary_Name,[Address],Address_2,City_State_Zip,Phone,Email_Address,Secondary_Email_Address,Create_Date,Last_Change_Date,[Status],File_Under,[Year],IsFavorite) OUTPUT inserted.Client_GUID INTO @myNewPKTable
                    SELECT c.Client_ID,Name,Secondary_Name,[Address],Address_2,City_State_Zip,Phone,Email_Address,Secondary_Email_Address,Create_Date,Last_Change_Date,[Status],File_Under,2010,0
                    FROM realforms.dbo.Client C
                        INNER JOIN realforms.dbo.Agent_Client AC ON AC.Client_ID = C.Client_ID
                    WHERE AC.Agent_ID = @Agent_ID AND C.Client_ID = @Client_ID

                    SELECT @Client_GUID = myNewPK FROM @myNewPKTable

                    PRINT 'Client GUID Inserted: '
                    PRINT @Client_GUID              

                    INSERT INTO realforms_2011.dbo.Client_Bucket_Client (Client_Bucket_GUID, Client_GUID, Client_ID, Client_Bucket_ID, [Year])
                    VALUES (@Client_Bucket_GUID, @Client_GUID, @Client_ID, @Client_Bucket_ID, 2010)

                    PRINT 'Client Bucket GUID: '
                    PRINT @Client_Bucket_GUID
                    PRINT 'Client ID Inserted: '
                    PRINT @Client_ID

                    SELECT @ClientCreateDate = CAST(Create_Date as datetime)
                    FROM realforms.dbo.Client C
                        INNER JOIN realforms.dbo.Agent_Client AC ON AC.Client_ID = C.Client_ID
                    WHERE AC.Agent_ID = @Agent_ID AND C.Client_ID = @Client_ID
                    PRINT @ClientCreateDate

                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    PRINT 'Error:'
                    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()

                    PRINT 'Last Client GUID Inserted: '
                    PRINT @Client_GUID
                    PRINT 'Last Client ID: '
                    PRINT @Client_ID
                END CATCH

                IF @@ERROR != 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER

                IF (@ClientCreateDate >= @MaxClientCreateDate)
                    BREAK

                FETCH NEXT FROM Client_Cursor
                INTO @Client_ID;
            END;

            CLOSE Client_Cursor;
            DEALLOCATE Client_Cursor;

            IF (@AgentCounter >= @MaxAgentCount)
                BREAK

            FETCH NEXT FROM Agent_Cursor
            INTO @Agent_GUID, @Agent_ID;
        END;
    CLOSE Agent_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE Agent_Cursor;

ERR_HANDLER: PRINT 'ERROR'

END
```

It breaks on @Client_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest fetch_status since the last statement of each loop is fetch next.

Comment: +1. Typically checking `@@FETCH_STATUS` always directly follows the fetch, so even in case of nested cursor loops you are always checking for the right fetch status.

Comment: Thanks guys!   Apparently my logic error was that my cursor had 0 items in it which was causing my skip of a GUID.